# Cron job bundler error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, whenever

I'm trying to create a cron job that runs a controller method with the whenever gem but i'm having trouble. I'm getting

> bundler: not executable: bin/rails

in my cron.log file.

**schedule.rb**

```
every 1.minutes do
  runner "Reset.reset"
end
```

**reset.rb**

```
class Reset < ActiveRecord::Base      
  def self.reset
    logger.debug("This is the cron job")         
  end    
end
```

I also ran the whenever --update-crontab to update the cron job.

Why isn't the logger message showing up in the log?

Thanks for all the help.

**Out put of crontab -l**

> sm start rvm
>
> sm end rvm
>
> Begin Whenever generated tasks for:
>   /home/john/rails_app/config/schedule.rb
>   PATH=/home/john/bin:/home/john/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/john/.rvm/bin
>
> GEM_PATH=""
>
> ***** /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/john/rails_app && bundle exec bin/rails runner -e development '\''Reset.reset_payments'\'' >>/home/john/rails_app/log/cron.log 2>>/home/john/rails_app/log/error.log'
>
> End Whenever generated tasks for:
>   /home/john/rails_app/config/schedule.rb

Comment: could you post the output of  `crontab -l` ?

Comment: I added the out put of `crontab -l`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation](https://github.com/javan/whenever/tree/main#define-your-own-job-types) states that for runner, the command looks like: `cd :path && bin/rails runner -e :environment ':task' :output`. But in your crontab it looks like: `...bundle exec bin/rails runner -e development...`

Run `crontab -e` and delete bundle exec manually or specify `job_type :runner` in your `schedule.rb` file, as in the [documentation](https://github.com/javan/whenever/tree/main#define-your-own-job-types). For me, this solved the problem.

```
job_type :runner,  "cd :path && bin/rails runner -e :environment ':task' :output"

every 1.minutes do
  runner "Reset.reset"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a rake task instead of using runner.